# Can somebody explain what is a spatially varying kernel?

Tags: python, image-processing, convolution

I have performed 2D convolution on image matrix using:
A. Matrix multiplication B. Fast Fourier Transformation.

My question is can I apply any of the above techniques (let's say FFT) for performing convolutions using spatially varying kernel?

My understanding is spatially varying kernel is applying different kernel on different parts of an image. But doesn't it violate the basic rule of convolution?

Comment: You can apply something that looks like a convolution, changing the kernel at every pixel (see for example the bilateral filter), but that no longer is a convolution, and you cannot analyze it using the Fourier transform, nor implement it through the FFT.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  So only way to implement it, is by using nested for loops?

Comment: Yes, that is the only way.